# self.view.bounds.size.height different values for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, position, frame

Okay, aside from the obvious dimensions differences, I think I may have a logic error in my code that causing this inconsistency.

I'm using `self.view.bounds.size.height` to determine the bottom edge of the screen and here's where the inconsistency lies.

For reference, `loadingView` is always a consistent size.

```
if (loading==TRUE) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [loadingView setFrame:CGRectMake(loadingView.frame.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height-loadingView.frame.size.height, loadingView.frame.size.width, loadingView.frame.size.height)];
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [loadingView setFrame:CGRectMake(loadingView.frame.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height+loadingView.frame.size.height, loadingView.frame.size.width, loadingView.frame.size.height)];
        }];
    }
```

I run the above function to show and hide a 'page loading' notification at the very bottom of my screen.

Heres' my issue:

iPad (correct):
[image]

iPhone (incorrect):
[image]

Now, obviously there's a height difference here and I'm not sure why it's occurring only in iPhone but not in iPad.

I'm trying to make my app Universal, and obviously, I don't want lots of device checks throughout my code. There must be a more elegant way to determine the bottom edge of the device.

Comment: Are you sure that self.view covers the whole screen?

Comment: Your comment led me to IB where I inspected the view heirarchy. Yeah, something was out. I resized the views and it immediately repaired my issue. Stick this in an answer and I'll mark you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that `self.view` is fitting the whole screen. (Double check your auto-resizing masks, etc. in IB.)

Comment: thanks mate! Appreciate the help pointing out my own stupidity!